# Prove that for $a>1$ $\Psi_a( n) \neq \infty$ $\forall a, n\in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: number-theory

> Let us consider successive powers of an integer $a$ $(>1)$. Let $\Psi_a(n)$ denote the exponent at which $n$ first occurs in the decimal expression. For example $\Psi_2(2)=1$ and $\Psi_2(3)=5$. Define $\Psi_a(n)=\infty$ if $n$ doesn't occur at all in the decimal expression for any exponent of $a$. Prove that there doesn't exist any such $n$ for any $a$.

I simply have no idea even to tackle the problem. Any help will be appeciated. Also, can an explicit expression of $\Psi_a(n)$ be determined only in terms of $a$ and $n$? How would the problem change if indtead of saying that $a,n \in \mathbb{N}$ , we would say that $a,n\in \mathbb{R^+}$?

Comment: What is the source of the problem, please?

Comment: You can show that for any integer $a>1$ but not a power of 10, and any string of decimal digits $n$, there is a positive integer $k$ such that the decimal expression for $a^k$ begins with the string $n$. A proof goes by noting that $\log_{10}a$ is irrational, so the fractional part of multiples of $\log_{10}a$ are dense in the unit interval.

Comment: Have you had a chance to think about my comment?

Comment: I thought about it but I can't get what it means to say that the fractional part of $\log_{10} a$ are dense in the unit interval. Can you be a bit more elaborate please?

Comment: I didn't say that. I wrote that the fractional part of *multiples* of $\log_{10}a$ are dense in the unit interval. So; what needs elaboration? Do you know what "fractional part" means?

Comment: Sorry, I missed the word. And yes I know what is meant by fractional part. But what is meant by the word 'dense' in this respect isn't clear to me. That needs elaboration.

Comment: To say that a sequence in dense in an interval is to say that every open subinterval contains a member of the sequence. Equivalently, it says that for every $x$ in the interval and every $\epsilon>0$ there's a $y$ in the sequence with $|x-y|<\epsilon$. Yet a third way to say it is that for every $x$ in the interval there is a subsequence converging to $x$. Oh, and if you want to be sure I'll be notified of a comment directed to me, you have to write @Gerry in the comment.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: That's clearer now. Thanks.